# Required String parameter 'email' is not present error in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to make a query to my controller in Spring MVC.

My action code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compile/{applicationId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String compileApplication(@PathVariable Long applicationId, @RequestParam("email") String email) throws ApplicationNotFoundException {
    ...
}
```

But I got an error:

> Required String parameter 'email' is not present

My main.js:

```
 var runCompileModal = function (options) {
        $(".modal-compile").each(function () {
            var modalNode = $('<div class="modal fade" id="compileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-sm">' +
                '    <div class="modal-content">' +
                '        <div class="modal-header">' +
                '            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                '            <h4 class="modal-title text-center">compile ?</h4>' +
                '        </div>' +
                '        <div class="modal-body">' +
                '            <p class="margin-bottom-lg">Are you sure ?</p>' +
                '            <div class="form-group text-center">' +
                '               <label for="email">@ Mail:</label>' +
                '               <input  class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" style="border:solid 1px black; border-radius:5px; text-align:center; box-shadow:0 0 6px;" />                                  ' +
                '            </div>' +
                '            <div class="form-group text-center">' +

                '                <button type="button" class="modal-btn-yes btn btn-success btn-gradient margin-right-lg">' +
                '                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>' +
                '                    <span>' + options.compileModal.yes + '</span>' +
                '                </button>' +
                '                <button type="button" class="modal-btn-no btn btn-danger btn-gradient" data-dismiss="modal">' +
                '                    <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>' +
                '                    <span>' + options.compileModal.no + '</span>' +
                '                </button>' +
                '            </div>' +
                '        </div>' +
                '    </div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>');

            $('body').append(modalNode);

            modalNode.find('.modal-btn-yes').click(function () {
                var email =  document.getElementById('email');
                location.href = $(this).data('url') + "/" + email.value;
            });
            modalNode.on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
                var modal = $('#compileModal');
                modal.find('.modal-title').html(button.data('title'));
                modal.find('.modal-body p').html(button.data('content'));
                modal.find('.modal-btn-yes').attr('data-url', button.data('url'));
            });
        });
    }
```

My app.html:

```
            '       <button title="' + compileTitle + '" class="btn btn-compile btn-gradient" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#compileModal" data-url="' + compileUrl + object.id + '" + data-title="' + compileModalTitle + '" + data-content="' + compileModalContent + '">' +
            '           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>' +
            '       </button>'
```

i have a new error when i include email parameter in url:

> TypeError: e is null

Comment: What does your code that performs the HTTP get look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like

```
location.href = $(this).data('url') + "/" + email.value;
```

should be

```
location.href = $(this).data('url') + "/?email="
    + URLEncoder.encode(email.value, "UTF-8");
```

Though I might be on the wrong track. (URLEncoder needs to be revised too.)

P.S.

FireFox with TamperData plugin or other tools allow interception of the traffic from and to the browser.

Comment: URLncoder is a JS function beacuase i have this error: URLEncoder is not defined

Comment: Yes URLEncoder is java, not JS. In JS `escape(email.value)` should suffice, see [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm) too.

Answer (score -1):

It means you are not passing email parameter from the front end(from client side).

Comment: how can i passing this param ?

Comment: make changes in the line location.href = $(this).data('url'); to include email parameter in url.

Comment: I do not see how to do this.?